# How do I get Alfresco to use the alfresco-simple-content-stores plugin?

Tags: alfresco

I've been trying to include the alfresco-simple-content-stores library (https://github.com/Acosix/alfresco-simple-content-stores) with Alfresco Community Edition, and it doesn't appear to be working. I've followed the documentation as best as I can, but I think I must be missing a step because my configuration appears to be completely ignored and there is no indication that it is running. I've done the following:

First, following this documentation (https://docs.alfresco.com/community/tasks/amp-install.html) I tried installing the amp using Alfresco mmt. That failed with the following message:

```
10250001 An error was encountered during deployment of the AMP into the WAR: 10250000 The following modules must first be installed: [acosix-utility-core:1.0.3.1-*]
```

However, no such artifact seems to exist.

As I couldn't get past that speed bump, I went down the following path:

1. I generated a keystore and a master key, referenced below in step 4
2. I included the following dependency in my alfresco/war/pom.xml (1.0.1.TEST is my locally compiled version of alfresco-simple-content-stores)

```
      <dependency>
           <groupId>de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores</groupId>
           <artifactId>de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores.repo</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.1.TEST</version>
           <type>amp</type>
       </dependency>
```

3. I copied the artifact to the Tomcat directory in my Dockerfile

```
COPY ./war/target/de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores.repo-1.0.1.TEST.amp ${TOMCAT_DIR}/amps
```

4. I defined the following properties in my alfresco-global.properties

```
simpleContentStores.enabled=true

simpleContentStores.customStores=myEncryptingStore,defaultTenantFileContentStore
simpleContentStores.rootStore=myEncryptingStore

simpleContentStores.customStore.myEncryptingStore.type=encryptingFacadeStore
simpleContentStores.customStore.myEncryptingStore.ref.backingStore=defaultTenantFileContentStore
simpleContentStores.customStore.myEncryptingStore.value.keyStorePath=classpath:../keystore/keystore.jks
simpleContentStores.customStore.myEncryptingStore.value.keyStorePassword=masterkeystore
simpleContentStores.customStore.myEncryptingStore.value.masterKeyAlias=ssl
simpleContentStores.customStore.myEncryptingStore.value.masterKeyPassword=alfkeystore
simpleContentStores.customStore.myEncryptingStore.value.masterKeyStoreId=alfkeystore
```

Despite all of this, files continue to be stored unencrypted and I see no indication that anything has failed. I doubt that this library would fail silently, so I'm left to assume that I've missed some step required to make Alfresco use this plugin.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
In response to a comment, here is the abbreviated pom of my alfresco/war project:

```
<dependencies>
    ...

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.acosix.alfresco.utility</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.acosix.alfresco.utility.share</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.1</version>
        <type>amp</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.acosix.alfresco.utility</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.acosix.alfresco.utility.repo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.1</version>
        <type>amp</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores.repo</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.PST</version>
        <type>amp</type>
    </dependency>

    ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    ...
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay />
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${alfresco.share.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <excludes />
                    </overlay>
                    <!-- other AMPs -->
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>de.acosix.alfresco.utility</groupId>
                        <artifactId>de.acosix.alfresco.utility.repo</artifactId>
                        <type>amp</type>
                    </overlay>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>de.acosix.alfresco.utility</groupId>
                        <artifactId>de.acosix.alfresco.utility.share</artifactId>
                        <type>amp</type>
                    </overlay>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores</groupId>
                        <artifactId>de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores.repo</artifactId>
                        <type>amp</type>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
    ...
</build>
```

Now with that pom configuration, the maven install output shows as follows (shortened to hide irrelevant path information):

```
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id de.acosix.alfresco.utility:de.acosix.alfresco.utility.repo]
[WARNING] Skip unpacking dependency file [.../.m2/repository/de/acosix/alfresco/utility/de.acosix.alfresco.utility.repo/1.0.2.1/de.acosix.alfresco.utility.repo-1.0.2.1.amp with unknown extension [amp]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id de.acosix.alfresco.utility:de.acosix.alfresco.utility.share]
[WARNING] Skip unpacking dependency file [.../.m2/repository/de/acosix/alfresco/utility/de.acosix.alfresco.utility.share/1.0.2.1/de.acosix.alfresco.utility.share-1.0.2.1.amp with unknown extension [amp]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores:de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores.repo]
[WARNING] Skip unpacking dependency file [.../.m2/repository/de/acosix/alfresco/simplecontentstores/de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores.repo/1.0.1.PST/de.acosix.alfresco.simplecontentstores.repo-1.0.1.PST.amp with unknown extension [amp]
```

Comment: The docs for the github project you link to makes it very clear that their utils package is needed too, what happens [if you install it first](https://github.com/Acosix/alfresco-utility)?

Comment: Thanks for your input! I installed this utility as per the instructions (via the maven-war-plugin) and the result is the same. See my above edit which includes the pom of my alfresco war project